# How to write a view to identify content with a date field without repeats

Tags: date, drupal-7

The website has a content type defined called an event, which is used in calendars and other displays. It has the following fields

```
Event
Label   Machine name    Field type  Widget  Operations
Title   title   Node module element      
Group   og_group_ref    Entity Reference    OG reference    edit    delete 
Date    field_eventdate Date    Pop-up calendar edit    delete 
Description body    Long text and summary   Text area with a summary    edit    delete
Booking Details field_eventbooking  Long text   Text area (multiple rows)   edit    delete 
Contact Details field_eventcontact  Long text   Text area (multiple rows)   edit    delete 
Downloads   upload  File    Multiupload edit    delete 
Retire from Front Page  field_retire_from_front_page    Date    Pop-up calendar edit    delete 
Key Words   field_key_words Term reference  Check boxes/radio buttons   edit    delete 
Meta tags   metatags    Meta tag module form elements.      
Location    locations   Location module form elements
```

The content type has been use for over 10 years and there are over 6000 records of this type.
The majority of the records are one off events with no repeats, but some are regular events with repeats set up for once a month meetings etc.
I would like to write a view to identify those records which do not have repeating dates, and for which the date is in the past so these can be removed from the system, but I can't see a way of identifying which events have repeating dates and which do not. 
Once the one off events can be presented in a view, View Bulk Operations can be used to remove them.
The repeating events are more problematic because some of them may still be in use, this would need to be determined as a second step or done manually.

The date module in use is Date 7.x-2.10.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be relatively easy just filter on
Content: Date:rrule (empty) to pick up records with no repeats
Thanks to Tony Maynard-Smith for the answer.